# Sample Work Experience Letter for ACS Skills Assessment

Tags: immigration, australia, skilled-migration, pr

I am new to the whole skill-based immigration process for the Australian PR (specifically skilled independent visa subclass 189). For the work experience verification letter needed, i have read posts that they are specific about the points in the letter. Can anyone here provide a example link to a template that can be used for this?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the page 13 of [this document](https://www.acs.org.au/content/dam/acs/acs-skills/Skills%20Assessment%20Guidelines%20for%20Applicants%20V5-6%20Aug%202018.pdf).

[image: Sample employment reference letter]